# Contact Form PhoneGap API + Javascript + HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am trying to create a contact form using the PhoneGap API accompanied with javascript and HTML5 for the form layout. By contact form I mean I want to be able to add new contacts and search for existing ones. So far I followed a tutorial/video off the Adobe Website to do this.

A few Notes:
* I have to use PhoneGap 1.9.0
* It has to run on Android 2.3.3 Level 10
* I am not an overly confident programmer

The code I have is:

JS

```
    $( document ).bind( 'deviceready', function() {

    $('#btnCreate').bind('touchstart', function() {
        var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
        var name = null;

        contact.displayName =
        $( 'txtFirst' ).attr('value') + ' ' +       $( 'txtLast' ).attr('value');

        contact.nickname =
        $( 'txtFirst' ).attr('value') + ' ' +       $( 'txtLast' ).attr('value');

        name = new ContactName();
         name.givenName = $( 'txtFirst' ).attr('value');
         name.familyName = $( 'txtFirst' ).attr('value');
         contact.name = name;

         contact.emails = [
         new ContactField ( 'home', $( '#txtEmail' ).attr('value'), true )];

         contact.phoneNumbers = [
         new ContactField ( 'mobile', $( '#txtMobile' ).attr('value'), true )];

         contact.save(function() {

             $('#txtFirst').attr('value', '');
             $('#txtLast').attr('value', '');

         $('#txtEmail').attr('value', '');

         $('#txtMobile').attr('value', '');
         }, function() {
             console.log( 'Error' );
         } );
    } );

    $( '#btnFind' ).bind( 'touchstart', function() {

        var fields = ['*'];
        var options = {
            filter: $( '#txtLast' ).attr( 'value' ), multiple:true };

            navigator.contacts.find( fields, function(contacts) {
                $( '#txtFirst').attr('value', contacts[0].name.givenName );
                $( '#txtLast').attr('value', contacts[0].name.familyName );
                $( '#txtEmail').attr('value', contacts[0].emails[0].value );
                $( '#txtMobile').attr('value', contacts[0].phoneNumber[0].value );
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error');
            },
            options );
    });

});
```

HTML5

```
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="contactContainer" >

<form id="lblFirst" > First Name: </form>
<input id="txtFirst" placeholder="First Name"/>

<form id="lblLast"> Last Name: </form>
<input id="txtLast" placeholder="Last Name"/>

<form id="lblEmail"> Email: </form>
<input id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email"/>

<form id="lblMobile"> Phone : </form>
<input id="txtMobile" placeholder="Phone"/>

<button id="btnCreate" data-corners="false">Create Contact </button>
<button id="btnFind" data-corners="false"> Find Contact </button>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: So?... r u getting an error or do you have any specific questions?

Comment: Well running this code on the emulator doesn't not work, I'm wondering why and was hoping someone could shed some light.

Comment: R u trying to run this as a website on the emulator or trying to run the .apk file created by PhoneGap?

Comment: I am running it is a website on the Emulator. Firstly, will that code work? Secondly, will it run as a website on the Emulator or not?

Comment: if you are running it as a website, you need to remove the deviceready event from the code as that event will only fired from PhoneGap. In your current code, nothing will work as the deviceready event is fired and no code is executed!

Comment: Okay so remove the DeviceReady Function, then will the code run in the emulator?

Comment: In the website it wont work as you are trying to run native functionality through PhoneGap. You need to create an apk file using PhoneGap and test it on the emulator.

Comment: I created an APK file and installed it to my phone, the buttons don't seem to execute the code, do they need an onClick ? or what am I missing?

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery Mobile for better touch experience. http://jquerymobile.com/ and use the button click event . http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-events.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [Contact plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) in Phonegap/Cordova. maybe [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10vQTzfL9s8) could help you out as it shows you how to use HTML5 and PhoneGap to create contacts on a user's mobile device..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [ContactPicker](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/ContactPicker) plugin for creating and searching contacts using native ui, all you have to do is to add the files yourself and update configuration files without using phonegap cli.